# Efficiently and scalably converting gamepad input to game logic input

Tags: c#, xna, monogame, opentk

I'm trying to create a function that accepts OpenTK's GamePad or GamePadState object and outputs a struct consisting of a [Flags] Enum with all the meaningful inputs for my game and their state based on an input map (dictionary?).  The idea is that the map can change arbitrarily to allow easy input reconfiguration, I can assign meaningful combinations of inputs useful names through the enum, and use the bit flags for funky other stuff.  It sounds like it would be very useful to have things set up this way.

It seems like it should be possible but unfortunately I've attempted this a few times now and every time it comes out a mess.  Can I get some suggestions for how to structure this please?

This is what I'm currently trying:

Inputs.cs

```
namespace F1.Input
{
  [Flags]
  public enum Inputs
  {
    None = 0,
    Up = 1,
    Down = 2,
    Left = 4,
    Right = 8,
    Neutral = -16, // ?
    D1 = 6,
    D2 = 2,
    D3 = 10,
    D4 = 4,
    D5 = -16,
    D6 = 8,
    D7 = 5,
    D8 = 1,
    D9 = 9,
    A = 16,
    B = 32,
    C = 64,
    D = 128,
    Start = 256,
    Accept = 512,
    Cancel = 1024,
  }
}
```

GameInputs.cs

```
namespace F1.Input
{
  public struct GameInputs : IEquatable<GameInputs>
  {
    Inputs inputs;

    public GameInputs(Inputs state)
    {
      inputs = state;
    }

    public InputState None { get { return GetInput(Inputs.None); } }
    public InputState Up { get { return GetInput(Inputs.Up); } }
    public InputState Down { get { return GetInput(Inputs.Down); } }
    public InputState Left { get { return GetInput(Inputs.Left); } }
    public InputState Right { get { return GetInput(Inputs.Right); } }
    public InputState Neutral { get { return GetInput(Inputs.Neutral); } }
    public InputState D1 { get { return GetInput(Inputs.D1); } }
    public InputState D2 { get { return GetInput(Inputs.D2); } }
    public InputState D3 { get { return GetInput(Inputs.D3); } }
    public InputState D4 { get { return GetInput(Inputs.D4); } }
    public InputState D5 { get { return GetInput(Inputs.D5); } }
    public InputState D6 { get { return GetInput(Inputs.D6); } }
    public InputState D7 { get { return GetInput(Inputs.D7); } }
    public InputState D8 { get { return GetInput(Inputs.D8); } }
    public InputState D9 { get { return GetInput(Inputs.D9); } }
    public InputState A { get { return GetInput(Inputs.A); } }
    public InputState B { get { return GetInput(Inputs.B); } }
    public InputState C { get { return GetInput(Inputs.C); } }
    public InputState D { get { return GetInput(Inputs.D); } }
    public InputState Start { get { return GetInput(Inputs.Start); } }
    public InputState Accept { get { return GetInput(Inputs.Accept); } }
    public InputState Cancel { get { return GetInput(Inputs.Cancel); } }

    #region IEquatable<GameInputs> Members

    public bool Equals(GameInputs other)
    {
      return inputs == other.inputs;
    }

    #endregion

    #region Private Members

    InputState GetInput(Inputs i)
    {
      return (inputs & i) != 0 ? InputState.Active : InputState.Inactive;
    }

    #endregion
  }
}
```

Input.cs

```
using F1.Input;
using OpenTK.Input;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace F1
{
  class F1Input
  {
    public Dictionary<GamePadButtons, GameInputs> buttonMap { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<GamePadDPad, GameInputs> directionMap { get; set; }
    public int gamePadIndex { get; set; }
    internal GamePadButtons gamePadButtons { get; set; }
    internal GamePadDPad gamePadDPad { get; set; }
    internal GameInputs gameInputButtons { get; set; }
    internal GameInputs gameInputDPad { get; set; }

    public F1Input(Dictionary<GamePadButtons, GameInputs> inputMap, int gamePadIndex)
    {
      this.buttonMap = DefaultButtonMapping();
      this.directionMap = DefaultDirectionMapping();
      this.gamePadIndex = gamePadIndex;
    }

    public void Update() {
      gamePadButtons = GamePad.GetState(gamePadIndex).Buttons;
      gamePadDPad = GamePad.GetState(gamePadIndex).DPad;
      GameInputs dictOut;
      buttonMap.TryGetValue(gamePadButtons, out dictOut);
      gameInputButtons = dictOut;
      directionMap.TryGetValue(gamePadDPad, out dictOut);
      gameInputDPad = dictOut;
    }

    public GameInputs getGameInputs()
    {
      return gameInputButtons;
    }

    private Dictionary<GamePadDPad, GameInputs> DefaultDirectionMapping()
    {
      return new Dictionary<GamePadDPad, GameInputs>()
      {
        // It was about here that I realized something is very wrong with my architecture.
      };
    }
    private Dictionary<GamePadButtons, GameInputs> DefaultButtonMapping()
    {
      return new Dictionary<GamePadButtons, GameInputs>()
      {
        { new GamePadButtons(Buttons.A), new GameInputs(Inputs.A) },
        { new GamePadButtons(Buttons.B), new GameInputs(Inputs.B) },
        { new GamePadButtons(Buttons.X), new GameInputs(Inputs.C) },
        { new GamePadButtons(Buttons.Y), new GameInputs(Inputs.D) }
      };
    }
  }
}
```

This doesn't work because (among other things) combinations of inputs don't work, probably because of how I'm using the dictionary.

Comment: If you show what you tried we may be able to help you. Currently it might be a bit too broad for a question

Comment: Alright but I warn you it's not pretty.

Comment: If you want the enum to work as a flags-enum, you have to define every value as if it represented a bit position. In other words, the power of two only. If you want it to be a regular enum, remove the flags attribute and use unique values. The idea of the flags attribute is to combine multiple flags of different meanings in to one value. In your case you want that combination in the dictionary not in the enum.

Comment: That's not necessarily true.  Combinations of flags still have a combined value in binary, the issue I wasn't thinking about was that combined flags weren't /exclusive/ of their constituent parts.  So yes, Down and Left combined to equal 6 and trigger the Down+Left flag (this demonstrably worked), but that didn't mean the flags 2 and 4 weren't also set.  I ended up getting rid of the Up/Down/Left/Right flags because they weren't discrete enough, and now handle checking of directions with stuff like (up+right OR right OR down+right) AND (input) != 0 to check if right is being held, etc.